# Android Studio backup of keystore

Tags: android, android-studio

Since losing the signing key for your app is pretty dire, it's obviously recommended to keep it safe and to back it up.

The [docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#self-manage) in this respect are a little confusing (for me at least), referring to an "app signing key" and a "keystore" as if these are separate things, and need to be managed and backed up separately.  Isn't the "app signing key" *part of* or *defined in* the "keystore", not different from it?

Anyway, just to be sure that I'm backing up all that I need, so that if my hard drive were ever trashed, or even when I'm just setting up a new workstation and want to recreate my IDE, is it fair to say that (so far as the app signing key is concerned) the **only** thing I need to back up is the **single** `.jks` file which is referred to in the `storeFile` part my `build.gradle` here:

```
signingConfigs {
    development {
        keyAlias 'MyKeyAlias'
        keyPassword 'mykeypassword'
        storeFile file('C:/Users/MyName/my-android-keystores/my-android-keystore.jks')
        storePassword 'mystorepassword'
    }
}
defaultConfig {
    signingConfig signingConfigs.development
}
```

Comment: Check my updated answer I hope it will be helpful for your security measures. I have updated it. You dont have to worry anymore for securing your apps.

Answer (score 2):

> Isn't the "app signing key" part of or defined in the "keystore", not different from it?

Yes, a signing key is in a keystore.

> the only thing I need to back up is the single .jks file which is referred to in the storeFile part my build.gradle here

You also need the `build.gradle` file itself or something else that has your passwords (e.g., a password safe).

Comment: yes good point, I am in fact already keeping a snapshot of the passwords part of the `build.gradle` (and anyway backing it up along with the rest of my project code to a private bitbucket repo), plus the `.jks` file itself separately.  So it seems that, with my project code (including `build.gradle`) plus the `.jks` file, I'm good to go if I ever need to recreate my setup from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

Keystore as a the name suggests it is a store that may contain many `keys` probably for many apps but it also related to your developing environment too.

But if you are worried about securing your keys consider  Using **NEW** Google Play App Signing as shown from this [link from the official source](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html).

> Because your app signing key is used to verify your identity as a developer and to ensure seamless and secure updates for your users, managing your key and keeping it secure are very important, both for you and for your users. You can choose either to opt in to use Google Play App Signing to securely manage and store your app signing key using Google's infrastructure or to manage and secure your own keystore and app signing key

Using Google Play App Signing It reduces worries because it will keep your Keys and you will have the Upload Key which is relatively easy to recover in case something goes bad this is a quote from the same link as above.

> When using Google Play App Signing, you will use two keys: the app signing key and the upload key. Google manages and protects the app signing key for you, and you keep the upload key and use it to sign your apps for upload to the Google Play Store.

You should consider visiting [the link again for more information on protecting your apps keys](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html).

Comment: Thanks.  I was already aware of the new App Signing option where you effectively transfer your key to Google for them to look after.  I'm reluctant to do that.  I'd rather be sure that I can sign the apk at my end and be sure that it isn't going to be altered by anyone down the chain.  Plus, I already back up my other important stuff (documents, photos etc) so including the signing key in the backup set is no extra bother.  Losing my app signing key would be no more disastrous than losing any of my other important data, so I can treat them the same.